# Android Custom BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a BaseAdapter to display a ListView with section.
For each row I have a TextView, now I want to add another TextView for each row.
In the `Item` class and in the `getView()` method, I added a new string `text_id`, but now when I call the Adapter I have this error: `Item(String, String) in item cannot be applied`.

```
public class AlphabetListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public static abstract class Row {}

public static final class Section extends Row {
    public final String text;
    public Section(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}

public static final class Item extends Row {
    public final String text;
    public final String text_id;
    public Item(String text, String text_id ) {
        this.text = text;
        this.text_id = text_id;
    }
}
private List<Row> rows;

public void setRows(List<Row> rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rows.size();
}

@Override
public Row getItem(int position) {
    return rows.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (getItem(position) instanceof Section) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) { // Item
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
        }

        Item item = (Item) getItem(position);

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView textView_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_cl);
        textView.setText(item.text);
        textView_id.setText(item.text_id);

    } else { // Section
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_section, parent, false);
        }

        Section section = (Section) getItem(position);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText(section.text);
    }

    return view;
}
}
```

in OnCreateView()

```
List<String> clienti = populateclienti();
    Collections.sort(clienti);

    List<AlphabetListAdapter.Row> rows = new ArrayList<AlphabetListAdapter.Row>();
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    String previousLetter = null;
    Object[] tmpIndexItem = null;

     for (String country : clienti) {
        String firstLetter = country.substring(0, 1);

        // If we've changed to a new letter, add the previous letter to the alphabet scroller
        if (previousLetter != null && !firstLetter.equals(previousLetter)) {
            end = rows.size() - 1;
            tmpIndexItem = new Object[3];
            tmpIndexItem[0] = previousLetter.toUpperCase(Locale.ITALIAN);
            tmpIndexItem[1] = start;
            tmpIndexItem[2] = end;
            alphabet.add(tmpIndexItem);

            start = end + 1;
        }

        // Check if we need to add a header row
        if (!firstLetter.equals(previousLetter)) {
            rows.add(new AlphabetListAdapter.Section(firstLetter));
            sections.put(firstLetter, start);
        }

        // Add the country to the list
        rows.add(new AlphabetListAdapter.Item(country));
        previousLetter = firstLetter;
    }

    if (previousLetter != null) {
        // Save the last letter
        tmpIndexItem = new Object[3];
        tmpIndexItem[0] = previousLetter.toUpperCase(Locale.ITALY);
        tmpIndexItem[1] = start;
        tmpIndexItem[2] = rows.size() - 1;
        alphabet.add(tmpIndexItem);
    }

    adapter.setRows(rows);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView temp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            String str = temp.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),str + " is pressed " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    updateList();

    return rootView;

    }
```

row_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/id_cl" />
```

Comment: where are you getting the error ?

Comment: the error line:  `rows.add(new AlphabetListAdapter.Item(country));`

Comment: and why does it surprise you ? Item's constructor takes two parameters

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way to accomplish this is to add another `TextView` in your XML layout file `R.layout.row_section`